# Correct way to make a query with using of many-to-many relation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I've created three tables - Podcast, Category and CategoryLink.
The CategoryLink table contains only two columns - PodcastId and CategoryId.
I have described many-to-many relations between these tables as written in this [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/08/01/creating-a-many-to-many-mapping-using-code-first.aspx).
All works fine but I don't know how to make query correctly.
Now I do this by the following way:

```
var ps = db.Podcasts.Where(p => p.Status.SysStatus > 0);
if (category_id.HasValue)
    ps = ps.Where(p => p.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == category_id.Value).FirstOrDefault() != null);
```

It works, but I think it's a little dirty way :-)

It give me the following SQL query (I've removed excess columns and strings):

```
    SELECT 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent3].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId]
        FROM [dbo].[CategoryLink] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[PodcastId]) AND ([Extent3].[CategoryId] = 1)) AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Podcast] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PodcastStatus] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[StatusId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent2].[SysStatus] > 0
)  AS [Project2]
WHERE [Project2].[C1] IS NOT NULL
```

The querstion is that how to do query so I can get a 'normal' `inner join` without sub-queries?

Thanks.

Comment: It's just houw EF builds queries, not much you can do about it. EF is very quick to use sub queries. At the end of the day, the execution plan is all that matters. I think that should be OK, because in fact, the part `WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[PodcastId])` is an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Many-to-Many is not much different from Many-to-One in the object mapping, except that you can access the relationship from both sides:

```
using System.Data.Entity; // For .Include Extension

// Eager-load Categories
var podcasts = db.Prodcasts.Include(x => x.Categories);
foreach (var p in podcats)
{
    foreach (var c in p.Categories)
    {
    }
}

var categories = db.Categories.Include(x => x.Podcasts);
foreach (var c in categories)
{
    foreach (var p in c.Podcasts)
    {
    }
 }
```

Depending on what you try to accomplish you might also want to do something like this:

```
from c in Customers
join p in Purchases on c.ID equals p.CustomerID           // first join
join pi in PurchaseItems on p.ID equals pi.PurchaseID     // second join
select new
{
c.Name, p.Description, pi.Detail
}
```

If you're new to LINQ I recommend taking a look at [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It includes quite a few examples that should give you an idea on how it works.

**Update**:

Could you maybe elaborate what you actually want to get?

The select in my second example can also be done without a `PurchaseItems` class:

```
var q = (from p in db.Prodcasts
        from c in p.Categories // note that it is using "p" instead of db.Categories
        select new 
        {
            Podcast = p.Name,
            CategoryName = c.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a PurchaseItems class in my model - only Purchases and Customers, as it was written in that article. In my case - Podcast and Category only. Now I understand that I have to add a model for CategoryLink table (PurchaseItem in your case).